# Python for loop behaviour issue

Tags: python, for-loop

I can't understand why this code is not giving me the intended results i.e replacing special characters like > with their special sequence like `&gt;`

```
def escape_html(s):
    for (i,o) in ((">","&gt;"),
                 ('<','&lt;'),
                 ('"','&quot;'),
                 ('&','&amp;')):
        s.replace(i,o)
    return s

print escape_html('>')
print escape_html('<')
print escape_html('"')
print escape_html("&")
print escape_html("test&test")
```

Specially because I am literally copy pasting this code from [this](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs253/l-48736183/e-48738174/m-48746045) Udacity lesson

The code is giving this output

```
>
<
"
&
test&test
```

instead of replacing these special characters with their escape sequences.

I am aware of the fact that Python has in built support for escape_html function, but I want to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are doing this manually - you're doing something wrong. This is a solved problem. Use a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the *return value* of `str.replace()`:

```
s.replace(i,o)
```

Set `s` to the result:

```
s = s.replace(i,o)
```

Strings are immutable, so all string methods return a *new* string object.

Next, you'll have to move the `('&','&amp;')` replacement to the top; otherwise you'll replace the `&` in `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&quot;`.

Demo:

```
>>> def escape_html(s):
...     for (i,o) in (
...             ('&','&amp;'),
...             (">","&gt;"),
...             ('<','&lt;'),
...             ('"','&quot;')):
...         s = s.replace(i,o)
...     return s
...
>>> print escape_html('>')
&gt;
>>> print escape_html('<')
&lt;
>>> print escape_html('"')
&quot;
>>> print escape_html("&")
&amp;
>>> print escape_html("test&test")
test&amp;test
```

Comment: Awww....F#@k me!!!!!! I knew I was making some really stupid error.

Comment: Might be worth saying that strings are immutable and that is to be expected.